# Dapper handling returned empty result set

Tags: datareader, dapper

We are using Dapper to map our sql data and so far it has worked very well. I have a case though where we are doing something similar to:

```
someObject = con.Query<T>("GetInfoSproc", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).Single();
```

This works great as long as the stored procedure I'm calling returns data. There are times where the stored procedure might not return a result and return an error in a out parameter.
This seems to cause a problem in Dapper because dapper throws the error:

*"When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id"*

Is there a way to write the query so it can properly handle the case when an empty result is returned or is this a limitation of Dapper?

Comment: I've opened an issue on google code on this for further discussion: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/detail?id=57

Comment: For those who may come across this question, I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720611/how-to-return-null-from-a-dapper-query-rather-than-defaultt) helpful.

Answer (score 6):

`SingleOrDefault()` is your friend here

Try this:

```
someObject = con.Query<T>("GetInfoSproc", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
if (someObject != null)
{
  // operate on your results here
}
return someObject;
```

also you'll need to make sure `T` is `Nullable`

Comment: If there is the possiblity that your SPROC may return a list of <T>, then SingleOrDefault will throw an exception. In that case best to use FirstOrDefault. See the Dapper docs: http://dapper-tutorial.net/querysingleordefault