# How to return null from a Dapper query rather than default(T)?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, null, dapper

I'm using [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) for some read-only database calls via a stored procedure. I've got a query that will either return 1 row or nothing.

I'm using Dapper like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    return conn.Query<CaseOfficer>("API.GetCaseOfficer", 
        new { Reference = reference }, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The returned CaseOfficer object looks like this:

```
public class CaseOfficer
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

This is then returned through a ASP.NET Web API application as JSON.

When the stored procedure returns a result I get the following:

```
{
    title: "Mr",
    firstName: "Case",
    lastName: "Officer",
    email: "test@example.com",
    telephone: "01234 567890"
}
```

But when it returns nothing I get:

```
{
    title: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    email: null,
    telephone: null
}
```

How can I get Dapper to return null (so I can check and respond with 404), rather than the default(CaseOfficer)?

Comment: FYI, default(CaseOfficer) is null. It looks like it is creating the object and just not populating the fields. Can't help you any more as I dont know Dapper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your SP doesn't return a row, then dapper won't return a row; so first thing to check: did your SP perhaps return an empty row? A row of all `null`s ? Or did it return 0 rows?

Now, assuming no row was returned, `FirstOrDefault` (the standard LINQ-to-Objects thing) will return `null` if `CaseOfficer` is a `class`, or a default instance if `CaseOfficer` is a `struct`. So next: check `CaseOfficer` is a `class` (I can't think of any sane reason that would be a `struct`).

But: dapper with `FirstOrDefault` will generally *already do* what you want.

Comment: SP is returning a row of `null`s by the looks of things. CaseOfficer is a class. Will see if I can modify the sproc to return 0 rows.

Comment: @James the other option would be to find a column that **must** have a value, and test that, for example `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FirstName != null)`

Comment: Does Dapper also return null when T is a nullable type such as `int?`?

Comment: @MarcGravell, if we use Query<T> to execute stored procedure and if stored procedure does not return any row, Dapper returns IEnumerable with count 0. How can we get null if no rows are returned from stored procedure? I dont want to initialize my list with 0 records. I want to set it null in such cases.

Comment: @Priya it seems to me that dapper is getting it *right* there... an empty grid is not null - it just has zero rows; but: if that isn't what you want, just check to see if it is zero rows, and if so: replace it in your own code with `null`. Dapper doesn't have an API for that in this scenario; if this was a single row scenario, you could use `FirstOrDefault<T>` / `SingleOrDefault<T>`, which would return `null` for any reference-type `T` if no rows were returned

Comment: @MarcGravell, Ok. If there are no rows returned from SQL stored proc, I don't want to initialize the List<T> variable. I want to keep it null. Can ExecuteReader help in this? Like we do the HasRows check in ADO.NET SQLDataReader? Thanks.

Comment: @Priya but *why*? that extra one object is not going to be relevant in the context of an ADO.NET query, so if your point is "to reduce allocations": this is not likely to be of any serious use; technically I guess Dapper *could* return `Array.Empty<T>()`, but it doesn't today, IIRC

Comment: @MarcGravell, yep, I actually wanted to do so to reduce unnecessary allocations. Also I need to build some logic if database returns empty result.

Comment: @Priya I *think* you're optimizing prematurely here; frankly, I don't think that is your bottleneck

Comment: @MarcGravell, Yeah, I think you are right. For now I will use the Query<T>. Will check the difference between null list and list with size 0 in terms of memory allocation. Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set default properties.

For example:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        if (GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity)))
        {
            var properties = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                // Get only string properties
                if (property.PropertyType != typeof (string))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!property.CanWrite || !property.CanRead)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (property.GetGetMethod(false) == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (property.GetSetMethod(false) == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) property.GetValue(this, null)))
                {
                    property.SetValue(this, string.Empty, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CaseOfficer : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

Now, CaseOfficer got auto-properties