# Default value for dapper multi mapped IEnumerable list when result is null

Tags: c#, dapper

I have the following code that is querying a database by stored procedure. When `ReturnObject.familymembers = multi.Read<InternalObjects.Person>().AsQueryable();` is not null, the return is fine; however I cannot find a way to handle a null return through Dapper / linq with a collection type.

My Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT    states.name as stateName,   fam.*
FROM            Family fam
WHERE        fam.idUserName=@username 

SELECT      person.*
FROM            person
INNER JOIN Family fam on fam.Id = person.idFamily
WHERE        fam.idUserName=@username
```

When the second SQL statement has records, setting `ReturnObject.familymembers` gives no issues, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to specify a default or handle a null return from Dapper. When debugging, `ReturnObject.familymembers = multi.Read<InternalObjects.Person>().AsQueryable()` throws a null exception if no rows were returned.

Here's What I thought would work, but doesn't:

`ReturnObject.familymembers = multi.Read<InternalObjects.Person>().AsQueryable().DefaultIfEmpty<InternalObjects.Person>();`

```
        public InternalObjects.FamilyDashboard GetDashboardInfo(string username)
    {
        InternalObjects.FamilyDashboard ReturnObject = new InternalObjects.FamilyDashboard();

        using (var dbConnection = _dbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var multi = dbConnection.QueryMultiple("DashboardSP", new { username = username }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
            {
                ReturnObject  = multi.Read<InternalObjects.FamilyDashboard>().SingleOrDefault();
                ReturnObject.familymembers = multi.Read<InternalObjects.Person>().AsQueryable();

            }
        }
        return ReturnObject;
    }
```

My DTO:

```
public class InternalObjects
{
    public class FamilyDashboard
    {
        public string physicalAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string MailingAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string physicalAddressCity { get; set; }
        public string physicalAddressZip { get; set; }
        public string MailingAddressCity { get; set; }
        public string NumInHousehold { get; set; }
        public string capidCounty { get; set; }
        public string physicalUnit { get; set; }
        public string mailingUnit { get; set; }
        public string familyPhone { get; set; }
        public string capCharacteristics { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Person> familymembers {get; set;}

    }
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string middleName { get; set; }
        public int gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
        public string emailPersonal { get; set; }
        public string SSN { get; set; }
        public string relationshipName { get; set; }
        public string primaryLanguageName { get; set; }

        public int age { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: What about the code isn't working?  What is actually happening that shouldn't happen?

Comment: @Servy - I updated my question with more information pertaining to the error

Comment: Why not do one query where you left join family to person?

Comment: @juharr - Per the Dapper documentation, multiple queries were easier mapped separately. I'm a little new to Dapper, but this seemed like the most straight forward way. https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multiple-results

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer:

Basically, dapper doesn't return any values if no rows returned, which doesn't instantiate my object. My parent object, `ReturnObject`, wasn't being instantiated, but was still executing fine.

The next line `ReturnObject.familymembers = multi.Read<InternalObjects.Person>().AsQueryable()` tries to access the object, but the DTO doesn't exist.

A simple conditional saves the day:

```
if (ReturnObject != null)
{
    ReturnObject.familymembers = multi.Read<InternalObjects.Person>().ToList<InternalObjects.Person>();
}
```

References for anyone else who runs into the same!:

[How to return null from a Dapper query rather than default(T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720611/how-to-return-null-from-a-dapper-query-rather-than-defaultt)

[Getting Dapper to return an empty string instead of a null string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944651/getting-dapper-to-return-an-empty-string-instead-of-a-null-string)